# Android - Tomcat - MySQL confusion, is this application design feasible?

Tags: android, mysql, jsp, tomcat, cryptography

I've had a look around the site for similar questions and nothing has been especially helpful. Sorry if I've missed the perfect answer that has been given before!

I'm building an Android app - it's pretty simple, it will allow registered users to access premium files online. The model I've been advised to use is connect the app to a web service (JSP) hosted on Apache Tomcat server and use this to access the files stored in MySQL database.

The web service will decrypt encrypted data passed up from the Android app and will also be responsible for encrypting the files in the database.

What I want to know is, does this make sense? Is there a much simpler solution that I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very subjective, You could use any number of server-side technologies to achieve this goal.

But to answer your specific question. Yes, it does make sense to use a servlet hosted on an Apache Tomcat server. You get the benefit of using Java on both the client and server. And MySQL is as good of a choice as any for storing data.

Whether there is a simpler solution really depends on what you know. I would definitely use the approach you where advised.